# How debounce use clearTimeout for last link function?

Tags: javascript

```js
function debounce(callee, timeoutMs) {
  return function perform(...args) {
    let previousCall = this.lastCall;
    this.lastCall = Date.now();
    if (previousCall && this.lastCall - previousCall <= timeoutMs) {
      clearTimeout(this.lastCallTimer);
    }
    this.lastCallTimer = setTimeout(() => callee(...args), timeoutMs);
  };
}

function mouseMoveHandler(){
  if(document.body.classList.contains('active')){
    console.log('1')
    document.body.classList.remove('active');
  }
  
     debounce(() => {
      document.body.classList.add('active')
      console.log('2')
    }, 3000)();
}

document.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoveHandler)
```

```css
    .active{
      background: aqua;
    }
```

```
function debounce(callee, timeoutMs) {
  return function perform(...args) {
    let previousCall = this.lastCall;
    this.lastCall = Date.now();
    if (previousCall && this.lastCall - previousCall <= timeoutMs) {
      clearTimeout(this.lastCallTimer);
    }
    this.lastCallTimer = setTimeout(() => callee(...args), timeoutMs);
  };
}

function mouseMoveHandler(){
  if(document.body.classList.contains('active')){
    console.log('1')
    document.body.classList.remove('active');
  }
  
     debounce(() => {
      document.body.classList.add('active')
      console.log('2')
    }, 3000)();
}

document.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoveHandler)
```

I don't understand how the debounce function understands how it clearTimeout the past function, how does it have a link to the past function if a new debounce is constantly being created in the callback inside? when calling the mouseMoveHandler function ?

for what reason does console.log("2") only work once after 3 seconds?

I would be glad if someone explained what kind of record

```
 debounce(() => {
  document.body.classList.add('active')
  console.log('2')
}, 3000)();
```

Comment: You can simplify your code by using `classList.toggle` instead of using `contains`/`remove`/`add`.

Comment: This code is pretty bad and hacky. It works because `this` inside the function is the global object. So it's basically setting `window.lastcallTimer` which is a global variable. It's a bad use of `this` - it would be more clear to just declare the variable outside the debounce function. Either way this is not how debounce functions are supposed to be used, they're supposed to return a single function that you reuse, and don't re-declare on every run.

Comment: Yep as @AndyRay points out, it is using `this` which is bound to the global object in this case. This is unintuitive and can be hard to debug so it's worth avoiding when possible. For example, what happens when you want to debounce two different events? do you declare a new function, change the global variable it's using and hope there is no collision?

Comment: Andrew Gillis with multiple debounce in this style, this will not work, u right!, Thank you.Now I understand